# Splitting CB Radio Mic Inputs?

Tags: cables, radio, bnc

I just purchased my first CB radio and I am looking to split the microphone's output such that it can go to two outputs (the radio itself and custom electronics I plan to design).

I'm using the [Uniden PRO505XL](https://uniden.com/products/pro505xl-40-channel-compact-mobile-cb-radio) and the microphone jack seems to have [an odd pinout that I've never seen before](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn7.bigcommerce.com%2Fs-47f02%2Fimages%2Fstencil%2F1280x1280%2Fproducts%2F860%2F5243%2FARS_9304_PNL_G4__64501.1502237400.jpg%3Fc%3D2%26imbypass%3Don&f=1&nofb=1). What is one simple solution that does not require me to cut the cable? I'm thinking sort of like the splitters that can bifurcate BNC.

Comment: `simple solution that does not require me to cut the cable?` ... a Y adapter

Answer (score 1):

CB radios use a variety of connectors, the most common being the 4 and 5 pin DIN types, with 4 pin Cobra/Uniden style being the very most common(what you would likely find at a truck stop).  You can verify which pinout your radio uses by checking the pins on the the CB socket with the microphone unplugged, noting which pin has continuity with the ground of the CB.

Once you have identified your pinout, you should simply be able to build an adapter cable(connectors are [widely](https://www.americanradiosupply.com/4-pin-microphone-electrical-cable-connector/) [available](https://www.americanradiosupply.com/cmc-4mp-4-pin-microphone-electrical-cable-connector-panel-jack/)) that splits the MIC signal and the ground out to another connector.  Since you are designing your own circuit, you shouldn't need to add any circuitry to your adapter since you could design your circuit with a high-enough input impedance to be able to rely on the termination of the MIC signal in the radio.

[Walcottradio.com](https://www.walcottradio.com/help/microphone_wiring.php) has an excellent illustration of the various pinouts("Mod"="Microphone"):

[image: CB Radio Microphone Pinouts]

Yours is likely the top-left most pinout in the chart...

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a Y Adapter for this style of 4 pin circular thread-mount connector.  But due to the metal work and uncommon style in low qty, you ought to expect 10 to 15 $ per connector or $30 per pair per port or ...  rather an expensive option.

Most likely the PTT switch has its own on pin pair but there may be shielding involved.

Good luck considering other options or finding a Y-splitter.  BNC T-connectors are pretty standard on the other hand. F-M-F  So are 3 pin XLR splitter quick connect cables.

But not 4 pin thread-mount circular connector cables

You can buy 3ft cable extenders though.
**https://www.walcottradio.com/cp436-pin-microphone-extension-male-to-female-feet-long-p-2516.html**  Then you won't have to move the plug very far. :)